# I need to create events in another Calendar with Google API

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I have my primary calendar, an also another calendars. 
I use Google API to create events on the google calendar, but those have been created on my primary calendar, how can I change that.
I want to create events on another calendar (not the primary/default) with the API Google.

Comment: Can you provide your current script?

Comment: Yep, https://github.com/DobleV55/remoto/blob/master/remoto.py

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the issue of the script. I apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: Isn't an issue from my script, The script reads the file: credentials.json that has the CalendarID and Calendar Secret ID, I want to know how to create events on another calendar of my own. If I change the CalendarID, it creates the events on the primary and I don't understand why.